# Как в react-leaflet при клике на карту получить адресс (улицу, дом и т.д.)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leafletjs, react-leaflet

Необходимо чтобы при клике на карту отображался адрес (улица, дом и т.д).Сейчас при клике у меня есть широта и долгота.

Как это реализовать? Отправлять запрос с широтой и долготой?